# GRecMutex reference count in glib >= 2.31

Tags: multithreading, mutex, porting, glib

I am porting a project to glib >= 2.31 and am having some issues with GRecMutex and its reference count. I the project there is code like this which is written for < 2.31:

```
GStaticRecMutex mutex;

int depth = g_static_rec_mutex_unlock_full (&mutex);
... code ...
g_static_rec_mutex_lock_full (&mutex, depth);
```

I can change the GStaticRecMutex to a GRecMutex, but glib >= 2.31 there is only g_rec_mutex_unlock(), g_rec_mutex_lock(), and g_rec_mutex_trylock() for GRecMutex and none of them return the reference count (depth). Are there any other functions that I can use to get this information? Can I access it directly?

Comment: Posted a bug report https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=719930

Answer (score 0):

> A GRecMutex should only be accessed with the g_rec_mutex_ functions.

That means the implementation details can change anytime.

File a bug if you need that function badly, but the question is rather why do you need it?

Comment: There are situations where you would want to completely unlock the recursive mutex, do stuff, then completely lock it again. I think I will file a bug because there was removed functionality.